# Localized Date (LongDatePattern) Remove the year

Tags: date, design-patterns, time, localized

I have this code to retrieve the Localized Date:
DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.LongDatePattern);

The thing is that it returns the year also. I don't want the year.

So I thought I could remove the year pattern from the LongDatePattern. But there are commas in some countries and it would look bad if I removed the 2013 year.

Can someone help me to be able to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.aspx) will allow you to supply a template that specifies exactly which components you want included in the formatted result ("month day dayofweek") for example.